# Thunderbird 52 on Linux: retrieve password

Tags: passwords, thunderbird, password-recovery

I am running Thunderbird 52 under Linux. I need to retrieve my password, from the "Passwords" tab but the security section has *no tabs* under it.

What shall I do?